# Laravel 5.7 authentication without login error: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to force an authentication without login with Laravel 5.7 like that:

```
public function login()
{

    $cpf = Request::only('cpf');
    $user = new User;
    $user = $user->where('cpf', $cpf)->get();
    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
    return redirect('/perfil');

}
```

And I get this error: `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`

When I debug the model User, all the attributes are there. But when I try to get the attributes, I get this error. What I'm doing wrong?

If there's any other way to authenticate without password, It would be helpful!

Comment: Typically one would say  `$user = User::where('cpf', $cpf)->get();` rather than instantiating a new object first. Regardless, what does `dd($user)` say? More importantly, what does `dd($cpf)` say? Is it a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cpf is a unique column, then the following will return the object you're looking for:

```
$user = User::where('cpf', $cpf)->first();
```

If you do ->get() as in your code, you'll get a Collection with exactly one object in it, and will need to do $user->first()->id.

https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using `$user` for anything else in the method, so you don't really need that object. You can use the `value()` method instead to get the id directly from the query.

```
public function login()
{

    $cpf = Request::only('cpf');

    // value() fetches the value of the specified column from the first row of query results
    $id = User::where('cpf', $cpf)->value('id');

    Auth::loginUsingId($id);
    return redirect('/perfil');

}
```

I'm not really sure about the authentication part, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function login()
{

    $cpf = Request::only('cpf');
    $user = User::where('cpf', $cpf)->first();
    auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);

    return redirect('/perfil');

}
```